# Docker-compose github action, local volume not mounted

Tags: docker-compose, github-actions

I'm currently trying to setup a service in my docker-compose file for production, which needs some local configuration files.

I have a folder in my main project folder called `prometheus` containing a prometheus.yml file.

My docker-compose service volume looks like:

```yaml
    volumes:
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
      - ./prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
```

Its working locally, but when i deploy this with GitHub Actions and `actions/checkout@v3`, if I log my prometheus container, I receive the following message:

> open /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: no such file or directory

EDIT: The relevant part of my workflow:

```yaml
name: CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ production ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.8.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.GHA_DEPLOY_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
      - name: Deploy
        run: |
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml down --remove-orphans
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml build
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d --force-recreate
        env:
          DOCKER_HOST: "ssh://${{ secrets.REMOTE_USER }}@${{ secrets.REMOTE_HOST }}"
```

Maybe I need one more step in my workflow to copy file to runner?

I tried to rm container, volumes, etc.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your workflow in your question..

Comment: @Azeem i updated my question. Maybe i miss a step to copy / paste my local file ? Its not really clear to me what happening here :/

Comment: Your checkout is on the GHA-hosted `ubuntu-latest` runner. But as you're using `DOCKER_HOST` with `docker-compose`, you need to run `git clone` via SSH on your remove machine before running `docker-compose`.

Comment: Check https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action and https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action.